# rm -rf returns error after upgrading to macOS big sur

Tags: jenkins, macos-big-sur, rm

I am running this command via jenkins,

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
```

but getting error:

> rm: /Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppDevelopment: Directory not empty
>
> script returned exit code 1

I'm expecting that -f should delete anything

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you do not have execute permissions for the dir

> /Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppDevelopment

And so rm can not list the dir content and try to delete its subfolders.

The quick way to fix it will be to run

```
sudo rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
```

The right fix will be to update the permission of all the dirs down the way to have execute access for your user group in order for rm to be able to delete the subfiles and subdirectories.